# Uncaught exception could not be opened: failed to open stream

Tags: apache, fedora

I hope for your support because i dont understand how to resolve this error.

[This is a error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQzcx.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, your question is very broad and misses a lot of information. What exactly is the problem, what lead to the problem. Which language are you using. Please provide more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the file at the location can be accessed by you. The file should have user level permission for you to be able to access it.

```
ls -l /var/www/html/deeplace-visits/var/logs/prod.log
```

If your user does not have permission then,

```
sudo chown [user:group] /var/www/html/deeplace-visits/var/logs/prod.log
```

Comment: [root@webdev0 /] $ cd var/www/html/deeplace-visits/var/logs/
[root@webdev0 logs] $ ll
total 596
-rw-rw-r--. 1 apache apache 593921 Aug 15 11:53 dev.log
-rw-rw-r--. 1 apache apache   6918 Aug 15 12:11 prod.log

Comment: You can try with - sudo chmod 777 /var/www/html/deeplace-visits/var/logs/prod.log